# How to change the size of the Xcode Playground Simulator when using live view?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I created a Swift Playground on my iPad and did all of my graphics positioning on the iPad simulator. Does anyone know how to edit the size of the Xcode playground simulator? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a liveView? You can set the size of the view you assign to it.

Comment: UIView has a bounds property with a size.  Set it. I could help more if you show your code.

Comment: @LouFranco I need the size of the Xcode playground liveView to be the same as the Swift Playgrounds liveView on the iPad.

Comment: Setting the size of the view (via either `frame` or `bounds`) has no effect on the size of the preview window in Xcode 9.2.

Answer (score 18):

To change the size of a playground's liveView, set the preferredContentSize of the viewController.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Comment: Setting the preferred content size of the view controller has no effect on the size of the preview window in Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Just tested and this answer is still working for me in Xcode 9.2. Pasted the above code into a blank playground and observed the Live View size.

Comment: @C.Lee  Having just tried this I can confirm that it does work, but **only** for widths <=768. For anything above that, the width just clamps to 768, so it's no use for iPad landscape. (This is on Xcode 10.3)

Answer (score 14):

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let viewController = UIViewController()
viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Seems to me this is the only working example at the moment (Xcode 12.5).
Setting the `view.frame` is the key here.

Comment: Can confirm as of Xcode 14.2 this is still the working solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 375, height: 667)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc.view
```

Comment: While this may be a correct answer, maybe you could add a bit of explanation to what this code does. Usually, code-only answers are not very informative because the reader has to interpret what's being done without much to go on. Thank you.

Comment: you're right. Instead of attaching view controller to the live view of the playground, we attach view controller's view. that's it.

Comment: Thanks! Please consider also adding it to the answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

## SwiftUI Solution

if you're using the **SwiftUI** on Xcode Playground Simulator when using live view... You can basically set the frame size before [setting the Live View.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundpage/3375752-setliveview)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Test")
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 700, height: 700, alignment: .center)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

That's it!